# Solidity Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have 2 smart contracts:
TokenContract:

```
contract BetToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    address[] betContractAddresses;
    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        address[] memory _betContractAddresses
    ) ERC20(_name, _symbol) {
        betContractAddresses = _betContractAddresses;
    }
    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        for (uint256 i; i < betContractAddresses.length; i++) {
            if (betContractAddresses[i] == msg.sender) {
                _mint(to, amount);
            }
        }
    }
```

Main Contract with function:

```
interface Token {
    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external;
}

function testMint(address _address) external onlyOwner {
        Token caller = Token(_betTokenAddress);
        caller.mint(_address, 1000000);
    }
```

I am trying to test this function with hardhat and got this Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string.
Test code below:

```
it("Testing bets", async () => {
      const [owner, address1, address2] = accounts;
      const sendToContractTx = await owner.sendTransaction({
        to: betContract.address,
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
      });
      await sendToContractTx.wait(1);

      const testMintTx = await betContract.testMint(owner.address);
      await testMintTx.wait(1);
})
```

I don't know how to solve this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you shared, it seems that the first transaction is failing:

```
const sendToContractTx = await owner.sendTransaction({
  to: betContract.address,
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
});
```

Your code doesn't show `receive()` nor `fallback()` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#special-functions), so I'm assuming they are not present in the contract.

When you're sending ETH to the contract address, is needs to implement this function to be able to accept the transfer.

```
contract BetToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    receive() external payable {}
}
```